# Could not build module 'UIKit' after upgrade to Xcode 10.0

Tags: ios, xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 10.0, my iOS project will not build.

The 2 specific buildtime errors are related to UIKit are:

> Parse Issue   ************Prefix.pch:12:13: Could not build module
>   'UIKit'
>
> Generics Issue 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIImage.h:176:88:
>   No type or protocol named 'CIImageOption' While building module
>   'UIKit' imported from ************.pch:12:

The second error points to the following line of code in the UIImage.h header.

```
- (nullable instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image options:(nullable NSDictionary<CIImageOption, id> *)options NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

I have removed and re-added UIKit from the target Build Phases, and I have tried adding CoreImage.

Comment: Quit and clean out DerivedData! Otherwise might need to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried both deleting Derived Data and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Well, it seems to be pointing to your _.pch_ file. Could it be something about that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, one more suggestion: can you build _any_ project at all? Try it with a vanilla project straight from the template. If you can build that, then perhaps there's an issue with your project, but you should be able to migrate your code into the new project.

Comment: I am able to build other projects. Would have preferred if nothing worked... My .pch file is identical to another similar project that does build.

Comment: "Would have preferred if nothing worked" I can understand that! However, I assure you that one cup of coffee and an hour later you will have successfully migrated into a new project. This kind of thing happens all the time: projects get unaccountably hosed. It's just a fact of life, and migration is a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue for Xcode 11.1 and i found that it happened after i have installed  a mistaken Xcode Command line tools for Xcode 11.0 cause i have not found the 11.1 version.

Anyway i have fix it by delete the newly installed Xcode Command line tools

1- Quit Xcode Totally

2- Delete this folder And Empty Trash

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Hope this would work for you too